# Invoke Excel macro recorder from code

Tags: excel, vba, vsto

I need a way to programatically launch the macro-recorder in Excel, and supply the name for the new macro that will get created.

This can be from VSTO or VBA, or using the Office interop assemblies.

Any ideas how this can be accomplished?

Comment: Well, I'm having a heck of a time getting my answer to actually work, which I tried to do when I figured out the name part.  It may be that they don't allow the macro recorder to be run like other menu items.  I'll keep digging on it.

Comment: I ran out of time today, I can access the object but the Execute command fails.  I'll work on it next week.

Comment: @Lance Roberts: Your code is working well on my side, so +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VBA:

```
Dim ctrlStart As CommandBarControl, ctrlStop As CommandBarControl
Set ctrlStart = Application.CommandBars.FindControl(ID:=184)
Set ctrlStop = Application.CommandBars.FindControl(ID:=2186)

ctrlStart.Execute

'name part would go here, but first you have to deal with a modal dialog

ctrlStop.Execute
```

It looks like the Execute method on the RecordMacro control opens a modal dialog.  There is no way to feed a parameter to this, or to do anything like SendKeys.  The only way I see to do it is to write a sub that will rename the macro after the fact.  It will be a little complicated to determine what the name of the new macro is, and you will still have a dialog box to deal with.